# SP2013 "_spUserId" is undefined

Tags: javascript, 2013, user

As we migrated our solutions and scripts from SP2010 to SP2013 my script ran into some weird error where I could not fetch the current logged in user with "_spUserId" anymore.

```
var user = _spUserId
```

As a workaround I'm using

```
user = currentWeb.get_currentUser();
```

now..

Anyone with an Explanation? Is _spUserId obsolete in SP2013? Or is this some local problem?

Thanks alot for your responses

Tom

Comment: _spUserId returned undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes `_spUserId` is deprecated in SP2013. Use `_spPageContextInfo.userId` instead.

Comment: They just moved the variable within the global context object.